# Simplest way to get a real linefeed saved in a text file

Tags: python, newline

I know that more hours of research will find an answer to this, but I have limited time. I want the data files that I create in Python to show up in editors with real blank lines (0A or 0D0A) rather than "\n". I want this because I need to human-read their contents, but they are long files with a lot of CSV data and a lot of HTML tags, so they appear as an unintelligible mess when I look at them in Notepad++.

I can't seem to get s.replace('\\n', '\n') to do the job. I've fooled around with os.linesep and other things, but my head is whirling. Can someone help?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why do your files have non-real linefeeds in the first place? How are you writing those files?

Comment: You want to human-read files that are long files with a lot of CSV data and HTML tags? That sounds like an issue regarding readability never mind new line characters... How is your replacement code not working - how are you using it? (Heck - does a rather nasty `open('outputfile.txt', 'w').write(open('inputfile.txt').read().replace('\\n', '\n'))` not work?

Comment: Daniel and Jon: Thanks, what was unclear is how I write to the files. I use a function that I wrote, and maybe the problem is in that. I'll experiment with this before asking for more help.

Comment: Yes, the function was a problem--but I'm not home free yet. The function tests for if the data is a list or dictionary and if it is (which this is) it uses JSON. So my problem is getting human-readable and JSON acceptable files. I can manually add newlines (hitting the Enter key in Notepad++) without disrupting JSON protocol. But I have problems when using json.dump(data, f).

Comment: So I should have stated from the git-go that this is a dictionary (with lists nested in it) and JSON is involved.

Comment: Holy Cow! JSON has a switch that takes care of this: indent=[number here]. Not realizing it was a JSON issue was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JSON switches do some formatting. E.g., =indent 4 will add newlines and indent the right amount for each level of sublist. Also, lists (or dictionaries) that are to be, eventually, opened with JSON can first be treated as strings and reformatted as strings. They still are opened as lists (or dictionaries) by using json.load(f).